# Self-quarantine requirements in NYC

Tags: new-york-state, travel

I'm planning to move to NY soon into an apartment or Airbnb I'll be renting. My understanding of the NY travel restrictions is:

- I need to get a PCR test *at least* 3 days before entering, and have the results negative.
- I need to self-quarantine for at least 3 days *after* entering NY.

My main question is: can I move directly into an apartment or Airbnb and quarantine myself there, assuming the living space is not shared with anyone? Or will I have to stay 3 nights in a hotel anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements for the space you quarantine in are laid out on [this page:](https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/covid-19-travel-advisory)

> - The individual must not be in public or otherwise leave the quarters that they have identified as suitable.
> - Separate quarters with separate bathroom facilities for each individual or family group. Access to a sink with soap and water, and paper towels is needed.
> - The contact must have a way to self-quarantine from household members as soon as fever or other symptoms develop, in a separate room. There must be a door that separates it from the rest of the living area and has its own bathroom. Given that an exposed individual might become ill while sleeping, the exposed individual must sleep in a separate bedroom from household members.
> - Cleaning supplies, e.g. household cleaning wipes, must be provided in any shared bathroom.
> - If an individual sharing a bathroom becomes symptomatic, all others sharing the bathroom will be considered exposed persons until the symptomatic individual is appropriately evaluated and cleared.
> - Food must be delivered to the individual’s quarters.
> - Quarters must have a supply of face masks for individuals to put on if they become symptomatic.
> - Garbage must be bagged and left outside by the door of each of the quarters for routine pick up. Special handling is not required.
> - Individuals should self-monitor for fever and other symptoms of COVID-19 daily throughout the duration of the quarantine period.

If your AirBNB meets these requirements, it should be OK.  However, a few of these requirements might be easier to satisfy in a hotel (particularly the garbage-collection one, and possibly the food-delivery requirement or the separate-bathroom requirement depending on the quirks of your AirBNB.)